# Pandas, trying to combine the values of columns as one mean value

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib

I'm a student who's relatively new to python and pandas/matplotlib etc. so take it easy on me please

I have a dataframe of a weather data .csv. I tried to split it into dataframes north, south, east , west and one df which contains the year columns to take it as the x-axis for plt.plot. My problem is:
I'm trying to get the df_East, df_West etc. dataframes which contain the columns of multiple states of the original dataframe as one df_East-column etc. which contains only one column with the mean value of all columns of each row because I can't plot e.g. df_East as one curve and compare it to df_North
If I made it sound complicated some pseudocode:
Temperature in degree celcius

df_East=df_All["stateInEast1","stateInEast2"..]

print df_East["stateInEast1"]=1990 : 12; 1991: 12.5 etc.

now I want df_East to be one column df_East["meanOfAllMyStates]=1990 : 12.3, 1991 : 12.7

so I can compare it at date 1990 with the mean of df_North and df_West's "mean column"

Comment: Hi, welcome to StackOverflow. Please go through [ask]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```py
df_East["meanOfAllMyStates"] = df_East.mean(axis=1)
```

Comment: The column "meanOfAllMyStates" doesn't exist yet, and if I try do run your code it says "A value is trying to be set on a copy of a slice from a DataFrame."
If I do the "df_East.mean(axis=0)" command into a new variable it still has all state columns which I don't want. So it combines the temperature of all years in "State1" into a single float value, same for state2 etc. But I want a single column with "AllStatesInOne" which has the mean value of all states each year (row) as one.

Comment: @KashRevil Hi, sorry I mentionned the wrong axis. it should axis=1 rather than 0. I just edited my answer

Comment: Omg thank you so much!! Awesome and sorry that the answer seems so simpled but I couldn't figure it out on myself :(

Comment: @KashRevil Glad that it helped. Consider validating / accepting the answer plz. Thanx